# Unable to see the newly created student in Internet Explorer?

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, caching, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC architecture.

I have a button called `Create New Student` on homepage And below that I have a table which have a list of all the students.

So whenever i click on a `Create New Student` button there a popup is open which asks for student details.

And after entering the information and clicking the `submit` button, It is sent back to the `homepage`.

But the new student should be added to the table having list of students.

This is working fine in `chrome` and `Firefox`
 . And i am able to see the new Student in the table.

But in case of Internet Explorer which i am using which is 8 and 9 . I am unable to see the new Student in the table. This is because Internet Explorer is storing cache.

When i restarts my internet explorer , the newly created student appears in the table.

So How i can make sure that it does not store cache.

Do i need to change my code inside the `controller` or `Jsp`?

How to clear the cache before the controller code executes using Server side code?

If you need either of these files or any other file, then let me know .

Comment: "Do i need to change my code inside the controller or Jsp?" -- what is your current code?

Comment: You can't clear the browser cache, you should prevent your page from being added to it.

Comment: @Jan How i can prevent it being built?

Comment: @Jan Something like this ?? response.setHeader("Pragma","No-cache");     
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");     
  response.setDateHeader("Expires",

Comment: Actually this is not a Spring question

Comment: That being said, do you do anything special to affect the HTTP headers or the `<meta ...>` tags that are sent to the browser? If so, what?

Comment: Add this to your head tag in jSP <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>

Comment: @Thinker your suggested headers look good Try them out. I also suggest adding some randomised content solely for the purposes of testing.

Comment: @Kris isn't an HTTP header better than a meta-tag?

Comment: @Jan Will Kris Solution also work? Is there any other question being asked before like this?

Comment: @JanDvorak not sure which one is better

Comment: @Thinker the meta tags should be equivalent to the http headers they override.

Comment: @Kris I vote for meta tags if http headers would need a custom servlet just for the purpose, for http headers otherwise.

Comment: ok. I will try both and let you know.